# Set a custom url for Codeigniter Controller

Tags: codeigniter

Please can any one suggest how to shorten the url

```
http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/index.php/Cpanel_control/
```

to

```
http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/Cpanel
```

in Codeigniter using routes.

I tried it in this way

```
$route['Cpanel'] = "MyWebApp/index/Cpanel_control";
```

But did not work

Answer (score 1):

To remove index.php from your url in CI, you need .htaccess file.
Check this out https://gist.github.com/philipptempel/4226750

I'm assuming Cpanel_control is a valid controller.

For the routing, you can have this in your routes settings

```
$route['Cpanel'] = "Cpanel_control";
```

To avoid any other issues, make sure base_url in config file is set thus

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp";
```

Answer (score 0):

### New Approach

Routing:

> In some instances, however, you may want to remap this relationship so
>   that a different class/method can be called instead of the one
>   corresponding to the URL.

A short excerpt from the CI doc shows that you can't use routing here. Instead you should go for a *mod_rewrite* rule (.htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index/Cpanel_control/(.*) Cpanel/$1 [R]
```

---

### Old approach

According to the [corresponding documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#examples), the paths are both not absolute. Furthermore, you need to set the "from"-URI as the array key and the "to" URI as the string. If you want to route `index/Cpanel_control` to `Cpanel`, you need to swap the URIs of you example.

So this would be correct:

```
$route['index/Cpanel_control'] = "Cpanel";
```

Comment: It gives me "The requested URL /MyWebApp/Cpanel was not found on this server" error.

Comment: @DilukshanMahendra Then check if your Cpanel-Controller exists/is configured correctly.

Comment: Yes, http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/index.php/Cpanel_control/ works, but http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/Cpanel doesn't

Comment: @DilukshanMahendra Then you misunderstood the concept of routing. What you want is a mod_rewrite via .htaccess!

Comment: @DilukshanMahendra Edited my answer for a new approach ;)